# Is multistage docker possible into FastApi application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I just create a single stage dockerfile in my basic CRUD application.
I want to multistaging because of reducing space of my docker image.
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client netcat-traditional && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY . .
COPY wait-for.sh .
# Expose port 8000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8000
RUN chmod +x wait-for.sh
CMD ["uvicorn", "index:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

So I do this in my Dockerfile
**Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as BUILD
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client netcat-traditional && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY . .

#CMD
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY --from=BUILD . .
COPY wait-for.sh .
# Expose port 8000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8000

RUN chmod +x wait-for.sh
CMD ["uvicorn", "index:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

But the second step cannot hold the index.py file.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev #Here change the Dockerfile and Dockerfile.dev 
                                 #Dockerfile for single stage and Dockerfile.dev for multistage
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    # restart: on-failure
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      DATABASE_USER: root
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: 12345678
      DATABASE_NAME: Student
    depends_on:
      - db
    entrypoint: [ "./wait-for.sh", "db:3306", "--", "uvicorn", "index:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000" ]
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Student
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345678
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

My question is "is it ever possible to dockerize my fastapi application with multistage docker?"
If it is possible how can I do this. Also If it is not possible then why can't I do this.
What will be the entrypoint of this?

Comment: People often use multistage builds for languages that require a compiler. The compiler isn't needed at run-time, so there's no need to include it in the final image. You'll typically see that the base images used are different for build and run-time. Python is an interpreted language, so there's no compilation step. That means that there's not much you can save by doing a multi-stage build.

Answer (score 1):

The image you've shown won't benefit from a multistage build.

The setups where multistage builds save space are if there are tools you need to build your image, but not to actually run the container.  For a Python application, libraries with C extensions need the C compiler, which is quite large, but only at installation time.  For those sorts of applications, the first stage can install the compiler and C header files, but the second stage only needs the corresponding runtime libraries.

An example Python-based Dockerfile could look like this.  Note that we're using the exact same base image for both the build and runtime stage, and the virtual environment is in the same directory.  The first stage installs `build-essential`, which includes a full C toolchain, but is quite large; the second stage doesn't need that.

```bash
ARG PYTHON=python:3.12-slim
FROM $PYTHON AS build

# Install (large) build-time dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      build-essential \
      libpq-dev

# Create a virtual environment that can be copied into the next stage
RUN python -m venv /venv

# Install packages into it
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN /venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM $PYTHON

# Install only the libraries you need to run the application
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      libpq5

# Copy the virtual environment from the first stage
COPY --from=build /venv/ /venv/
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

# The rest of your Dockerfile as before
...
CMD ["uvicorn", ...]
```

You also asked about a correct value for an entrypoint.  This doesn't change in a multistage build, noting that only the value from the final image is used.

You shouldn't normally need to override the `entrypoint:` in the Compose file, and many cases do not need to override `command:` either.  I might move the call to `wait-for.sh` into the Dockerfile

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for.sh", "db:3306", "--"]
CMD ["uvicorn", ...]
```

A more robust solution could be to wrap it in a dedicated shell script, that honors the deploy-time database hostname

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Wait for the database to be ready
if [ -n "$DATABASE_HOST" ]; then
  ./wait-for.sh "$DATABASE_HOST:3306"
fi

# Switch to the main container command
exec "$@"
```

This script can be the image's `ENTRYPOINT` (make sure to use JSON-array syntax), and you don't need to put anything special in the Compose file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create docker image with multistage-build for application that uses fastAPI. For your second question the entry point will remain the same.

Although for cases like this multi-stage build is likely to provide less value (save less space) for interpreted languages like python as your specific case. If you still wish to approach this, You can approach it in a similar way for creating different stages for build and runtime environment for compiled languages.

You can consider the below example:

```
# Stage 1: Build environment
FROM python:3.9 AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

For the second stage you can create a runtime environment for your purpose.

```
# Stage 2: Runtime environment
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app /app

# Copy your FastAPI app code
COPY . .

# Set the entry point
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

keep in mind that multistage builds usually benefit cases where you need to build the container without running or running the container doesn't require entirety of the build tools. [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78230649/13822595)'s answer is more appropriate for you specific use case.